# How to auto advance a ListView app widget like the StackView app widgets on Honeycomb?

Tags: android, animation, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-appwidget

I'm looking for a way to animate/auto-advance periodically a ListView app widget as it is done with StackView app widgets.

For example, the Android Market and YouTube widgets do animate every 20s by auto advancing to the next item in the collection  (on Honeycomb).

I have seen in the [StackView Widget example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/res/xml/stackwidgetinfo.html) that they use a autoAdvanceViewId setting for the StackView widget :

```
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:minWidth="150dip"
  android:minHeight="150dip"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000"
  android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
  android:autoAdvanceViewId="@id/stack_view">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Can this be done or emulated in some way for a ListView app widget?

Many thanks,
Laurent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### I found one solution, but it might not be ideal!

I set a **repeating alarm** in the onEnable() of the AppWidgetProvider and cancel it in the onDisabled(). That alarm triggers a BroadcastReceiver that updates the widget views and use **setRelativeScrollPosition()** on the RemoteView.

Here's a few lines of code:

- In the class extending AppWidgetProvider

  ```
  public void onEnabled(Context context) {
      [...]
    // create alarm that will move the widget list content every n seconds
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    firstTime += 10*1000;

    Intent i = new Intent(context, WidgetAutoScroller.class);
    PendingIntent widgetAutoScroll = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, firstTime, 
          10*1000, widgetAutoScroll);
    super.onEnabled(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // deactivate the alarm that moves the widget content 
    Intent i = new Intent(context, WidgetAutoScroller.class);
    PendingIntent widgetAutoScroll = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(widgetAutoScroll);
    super.onDisabled(context);
  }
  ```
- WidgetAutoScroller.java

`public class WidgetAutoScroller extends BroadcastReceiver {`

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, CascadeWidgetProvider.class));

        for( int i=0 ; i<appWidgetIds.length ; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            RemoteViews rv = CascadeWidgetProvider.getWidgetView(context, appWidgetId);
            rv.setRelativeScrollPosition(R.id.widget_collection, 1);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
        }
    }
}
```

**If you have a better solution to my problem, please answer.**

**EDIT**: Another problem is: what to do when I reach the end of my list? 
I would want to go to the first item of the list, but I don't know how to get the current position of the list from my RemoteView or appWidgetId ...